# Identifying Left and Right Mouse Button Clicks in PyQgis application

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis

Hi guys I am relatively new to PyQt. I am trying create a custom plugin for Qgis which enables the user to select some features by drawing polygon on the canvas using mouse clicks and then performs intersection of the selected features with another layer. What I want to do is that when user right clicks on the canvas the polygon selection should stop. For this I have to identify between the right and left mouse signals. I have made a dummy function just to test this functionality:

```
def mousePressEvent(self):
   print "code enters mousePressEvent function"
   if event.buttons() == "Qt::LeftButton"
   print"Left button pressed"
```

I am calling this function as follows:

```
QObject.connect(self.clickTool,SIGNAL("canvasClicked(QMouseEvent,Qt::MouseButton)"),self.mousePressEvent)
```

But I am unable to call the function. I guess I am doing something wrong in canvasClicked section. Any help in this matter would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please ignore the indentation error

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is to use the **QgsMapToolEmitPoint** object. An example would be:

In your code, create a variable called emitPoint and in the **run()** function set it:

```
self.emitPoint = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.mapCanvas)
QObject.connect(
     self.emitPoint,
     SIGNAL("canvasClicked(const QgsPoint &, Qt::MouseButton)"),
     self.clickedOnMap)
```

and create a function:

```
def clickedOnMap(self, pointOnMap, buttonUsed):
  if (button==Qt.LeftButton):
      ....
```

the buttonUsed parameter has one of the values in the enum Qt::MenuButtons (as you can see in the link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#MouseButton-enum).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @luca76 I am already doing what you said up there. In my code the self.clickTool is equivalent to your self.emitPoint. The issue is that the clickedOnMap function never gets called no matter what plus I do not get any error.

Comment: Can you show me some code? I suspect that you are missing some parameters.

Comment: I got it right finally.  You were right @luca76. I was messing up with the arguments and that is why the function was not being called, although I wonder why it did'nt throw any error. Anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: sorry don't have enough repo :)

Comment: Ok :-) have a nice day!